# React setState not triggering a re-render with Contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React component that updates its state after making a request. 
In the render function of this component, I am creating a context provider and passing in the value of the state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: 'defaultValue',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        makeAxiosRequest()
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                text: 'updatedValue'
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }) 
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.text)
        return (
            <div>
                <MyContext.Provider value={{
                    text: this.state.text
                }}>
                    <SomeComponent />
                </MyContext.Provider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Then, In the child component, I am trying to get that value from the context.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    static contextType = MyContext;
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        console.log(this.context.text)
    }
}
```

However, the value in the context in `SomeComponent` is 'defaultValue', instead of the updated value.

The final console log is:

```
defaultValue
defaultValue
updatedValue
```

Shouldn't it instead be

```
defaultValue
defaultValue
updatedValue
updatedValue
```

because when the value is updated, then a re-render should be triggered and context should be updated. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did your SomeComponent contain a **render()** method? If no, rerender would not happen. The updatedValue is print by the parent render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeComponent`'s `constructor()` only gets called when the component mounts, not when it re-renders.  In order to see the new context value you would need to put your `console.log(this.context.text)` inside its `render()` or a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate()`.